# How can I rotate an object to face a target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My bat stays still in the air.

How can i check that the player, that is moving right below on x axis, comes from the left or right side relative to the bat?

```
public class Bat : MonoBehaviour
{
    Player player;

    void Start()
    {
        player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
       
        if (transform.InverseTransformPoint(player.transform.position).x >= 0)
            transform.rotation = new Quaternion(transform.rotation.x, 0f, transform.rotation.z, 0f);
        else
            transform.rotation = new Quaternion(transform.rotation.x, -180f, transform.rotation.z, 0f);
    }
}
```

As you may notice i try to flip the the Bat so it actually looks at the player.

Comment: Would getting their locations (x values) and comparing their values enough to solve your problem? In essence: higher X value = further away on the x axis, therefore coming from the right.

Comment: In combination with @Lae's answer, you could also check if the player's rigidbody.velocity.magnitude > 0. This will indicate whether or not the player is currently moving (as specified in your question).

Comment: When you say you want to make the bat look at the player, do you mean you want the bat's local `forward` (blue arrow) to point toward the player? or its local `right`? (red arrow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use `new Quaternion(...);` unless you absolutely, 100% know quaternions inside and out. For instance, having the w component be 0 results in zero effective rotation. Also, quaternions use unitless figures and not degrees for their components. [See here](https://quaternions.online/) for a nice visualization of what different quaternion values might look like, under <kbd>Quaternion</kbd>).

Second, your logic is weird because if the bat has zero (identity) rotation, and the player is on the left of the bat, then your logic tries to* flip the bat 180 degrees, so that the player is now on the right side of the bat.

Then, the next frame assuming the bat and player are still in the same positions, the logic says oh the player is on the right side, set the rotation to zero (identity) rotation, which is of course what it was in the first place. So basically, you would have the bat rotate 180 degrees again so that the player is once again on the left side of the bat.

And so, you could get into a situation where every frame, the bat would flip a complete 180. Definitely not desired.

* I'm assuming if you had used [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html)[`(transform.eulerAngles.x, 0f, transform.eulerAngles.z)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) etc.

---

Instead of concerning with any of that, use [`Vector3.Cross`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) to find the forward the bat should point so its right faces the player's position. Then, use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to set the rotation of the bat to point in that forward direction:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 batRightDir = player.transform.position - transform.position;

    Vector3 batForwardDir = Vector3.Cross(batRightDir, Vector3.up);

    if (batForwardDir.sqrMagnitude == Vector3.zero) 
    {
        // player above or below bat. do nothing?
        return;
    }

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(batForwardDir);
}
```

If you have the player on a different z as the bat, this will cause the bat to rotate around the y axis accordingly, which is what you would want from a 3d game, and could be a neat effect for a 2d game if you want that kind of effect.

---

If you want it to ignore the z position of the player, you could zero out the z component of `batRightDir`...

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 batRightDir = player.transform.position - transform.position;
    batRightDir.z = 0; // ignore Z differences between bat and player

    Vector3 batForwardDir = Vector3.Cross(batRightDir, Vector3.up);

    if (batForwardDir.sqrMagnitude == Vector3.zero) 
    {
        // player above or below bat. do nothing?
        return;
    }

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(batForwardDir);
}
```

or it may be more intuitive to branch as you were previously:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 batRightDir = player.transform.position - transform.position;

    if (batRightDir.x > 0)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }
    else if (batRightDir.x < 0)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.back);
    }
    else 
    {
        // player above or below bat. do nothing?
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the access to his Rigidbody and than call it.
If Rigidbody.velocity.x > 0 he is moving to the right. If it's <0 it's moving to the left. All is related to X axis of course.